# Grant users to create database with username

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin I want to grant users to create and delete databases but this access should be limited to a specific prefix.

My users have 3 different accounts on PhpMyAdmin: `username_ro` (for only reading), `username_rw` (for reading and writing) and `username_admin` (for creating other databases and tables into their account)

I want them to be able to create a database `username_website` but I don't want them to be able to create database `theother_website`. They should also be able to drop `username_website` but unable to drop `theother_website`

How can I do this with sql or PhpMyAdmin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With some trial and error I have found a solution. By doing this query I was able to create and drop database `username_website` but I wasn't able to create or drop database `theother_clients`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES
ON `username\_%`.* 
TO 'username_admin'@'localhost';
```

PS. the query is a little edited. I changed the rights I actually gave with `ALL PRIVILIGES`and I changed the actual username with username.